# How to listen to the submit event of a form in a meteorjs template?

Tags: meteor, handlebars.js

If I have a template like this

```
<template name="my_form">
  <form name="my_form">
    <input name=" ....
  </form>
</template>
```

I'd like to listen to the submit event of "my_form".

I tried this:

```
Template.my_form.events({
  'submit form': function( event ){   // also tried just 'submit'
    console.log( 'Submitting form!' );
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    return false; 
  }
});
```

But no luck. It appears the event handler doesn't get registered. Is there something I'm missing?

p.s. I am aware that I can handle a form "submission" by listening to the submit button click event, but I need to use the form submit event in this specific scenario.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Doesn't seem like you are missing something. I was not able to reproduce your problem. When hitting return while the textinput has focus the console prints 'Submitting form!' as expected.

My code, just two files:

**form.html:**

```
<head>
  <title>form</title>
</head>

<body>
  {{> my_form}}
</body>

<template name="my_form">
  <form name="my_form">
    <input></input>
  </form>
</template>
```

**form.js**

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
    Template.my_form.events({
      'submit form': function( event ){   // also tried just 'submit', both work for me!
        console.log( 'Submitting form!' );
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
        return false; 
      }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, it helped me find the issue.. I was submitting the form via $( /**form here**/ ).submit(); on the submit button (which was an anchor) click event.. Apparently that doesn't trigger the form's submit event...

Comment: For anybody wondering, I fixed it by adding a hidden input of type submit and then calling $form.find('input[type="submit"]').click() from my anchor instead of $form.submit(); This seems to work well and it calls the form submit handler.

Answer (score 2):

You can use general listener for it.

```
$("my_form").submit(function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: @Cuberto this will actually work if you detach and re-attach the listener when the template renders/unloads using the built in hooks, but that's a hassle. I want to use the built in template events.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a single submit form event, and you conditionally check the event target field. Call appropriate Meteor method based on the collection you are inserting into.

```
Template.detailsViewTemplate.events({
    'submit form': function(ev){
        ev.preventDefault();

        var detail_input_field = template.$('#detail_entry');
        var message_input_field = template.$('#message_entry');

        if(detail_input_field != undefined){
            var detailFormData = {
            detail: $(ev.target).find('[name = detail]').val(),
            parentId: $(ev.target).find('[name = parentId]').val(),
            checkboxStatus: ''
            }

            Meteor.call('addDetail', detailFormData);
            $('.form-group').children().val('');

        } else if(message_input_field != undefined){
            var newMessageData = {
                listId: this.params_id,
                message: $(ev.target).find('[name = message]').val()
            }
            Meteor.call('addMessage', newMessageData);
            $('.form-group').children().val('');
        }
    }
}
```